# Out of range number giving unexpected output

Tags: c, loops

I have this number guessing game where Player 1 inputs a number, and Player 2 must guess that number. If the number Player 2 inputs is more than 1000, "That number is out of range is printed."

```
int player2(int number)
{
    int i, currentGuess;
    printf("Player 2, you have 10 guesses remaining\n");
    //For Player 2
    for (i = 1; i <= MAX_GUESS; i++) {

        int remaining = MAX_GUESS - i;
        printf("Enter your guess:\n");

        scanf_s("%i", &currentGuess);

        if (currentGuess > 1000) {
            printf("That number is out of range.\n");

        }

        else if (currentGuess > number) {
        printf("Too high.\n");
        printf("Player 2, you have %i guesses remaining\n", remaining);
        if (remaining == 0) {
            printf("Player 1 wins\n");
        }
    }


    else if (currentGuess < number) {
        printf("Too low.\n");
        printf("Player 2, you have %i guesses remaining\n", remaining);
        if (remaining == 0) {
            printf("Player 1 wins\n");
        }
    }

    else if (currentGuess = number) {
        printf("Player 2 wins\n");
        return 0;

    }

}

return i;


}
```

If Player 2 inputs 1001, the correct message "This number is out of range." will be given. Problem is that if Player 2 inputs 11111111, the output message "Too low." is given instead of "This number is out of range." Why is this so?

Comment: What is your target system (operating system and hardware)? What is the size of `int` on your system? What does [`scanf_s` *return*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value)? And have you tried to step through your code statement by statement in a debugger?

Comment: There is a problem with `}`. Looks like one `}` too many? Please check. Does the program compile?

Comment: the check works for me (debian linux, so using scanf instead of scanf_s) and I get "out of range".  also mind that `if (currentGuess = number)` is an assignment, not a comparison. you may want to use == instead

Comment: @Tommylee2k The only way the OP could have the mentioned problems with the mentioned values, is if `int` is 16 bits. I don't think there are any Linux system which doesn't have 32-bit `int`. To replicate the problems, one have to be running DOS or other similarly antiquated systems (or some embedded hardware).

Comment: that, or we have him adding a `printf ("your guess:%i", currentGuess);` to see if it's the number he entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an integer overflow here. Your number is too big and it's interpreted as a negative number.

Change the declaration of your variables to:

```
unsigned int i, currentGuess;
```

In addition, you can limit your scan clause to avoid such a problem:

```
scanf_s("%5d", &currentGuess);
```

Comment: Ah I see, so that's what caused the problem.

Comment: His `int` has to be 16 bit wide that `11111111` overflows, so also `uint16_t` will result in an overflow. But this might luckily result in a number which still is `> 1000` but for other big input values this will fail too

Comment: @wei1999 You might want to resort to using `long` in your code instead, as it could be bigger than `int` (and considering that `int` on your system seems to be only 16 bits, then `long` should be 32 bits).

Comment: @Odysseus Yes, I was aware of that, wasn't sure if he put the right amount of `1` in the question. Anyways, to use `%5d` should solve his issue either way.